# SQL creating table error

Tags: sql, oracle11g

We are using Oracle 11g to create our tables and database. If I create a table EX

```
CREATE TABLE  "ALIASES" 
   (    "ALIAS_ID" NUMBER(6), 
    "CRIMINAL_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "ALIAS" VARCHAR2(20)
   ) ;
```

Then it creates the table fine, but when I try to create multiple tables at a time 
EX

```
CREATE TABLE  "ALIASES" 
   (    "ALIAS_ID" NUMBER(6), 
    "CRIMINAL_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "ALIAS" VARCHAR2(20)
   ) ;



   CREATE TABLE  "CRIMINALS" 
   (    "CRIMINAL_ID" NUMBER(6,0), 
    "LAST" NUMBER(15,0), 
    "FIRST" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "STREET" VARCHAR2(10), 
    "CITY" VARCHAR2(20), 
    "STATE" CHAR(2), 
    "ZIP" CHAR(5), 
    "PHONE" CHAR(10), 
    "V_STATUS" CHAR(1), 
    "P_STATUS" CHAR(1)
   ) ;
```

then I get a ORA-00911: invalid character error. 
How can I get an error from 2 tables that both work if I did them seperately, but dont work if I do them together.

Comment: Where do you run these statements? Which SQL tool do you use? Maybe your SQL tool doesn't support running multiple statements?

Comment: We are using oracle 11g express edition. It is the only software the teacher said we would need.(SQL workshop)

Comment: Oracle 11g XE is not a "SQL client". It's the DBMS. You need to tell which tool you use to _run_ the SQL statements (SQL*Plus, SQL Developer, some other tool...)

Comment: You can create two tables without a `/` .. I just checked on [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3986b9)

Comment: We didnt actually have one I just downloaded SQL developer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied Your code into file named test.sql then ran sqlplus, and got the answer:

```
SQL> @test

Table created.


Table created.

SQL>
```

Check the encoding of the file or the tool You use.

Comment: this is the whole table chart if there is anyway you can see why it wont work with the full thing
http://pastebin.com/6guMREXa

Comment: Unfortunatelly I'm behind the corporate firewall. Try run the script with Oracle sql developer and post the error.

Comment: I think I got it to work, so it was just my program couldnt process more then one table at a time, Thank you